# Really force http to https in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I have this Laravel App which I'm deplying to Heroku.
I have followed all of the steps until I encountered a problem relating some assets (asset('css/app.css'), for example) refering to http urls, instead of https urls.

I solved that by adding

```
if(config('app.env')==='production'){
            \URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

in the boot method of my AppServiceProvider.php file, and it worked.

But now I have encountered another http related problem that the previous code couldn't solve.

I am fetching my data using simplePaginate() function like so

```
    public function index(Question $question){
        $answers = $question->answers()->with('user');
        return  $answers->simplePaginate(3);
    }
```

This code returns me a response with my 3 answers, as well as with a property called 'next_page_url'
which is, still, plain http (not https as i need it to be).

What can I do for this to be https as Heroku requires?
[image: Here you can see the next_page_url property in http]

Comment: Have you configured Laravel's trusted proxy? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies Without this, it can't detect that Heroku is serving it over HTTPS.

Comment: @ceejayoz, The file was already created exactly like in the Docs example, but the problem happens anyway

Comment: @ceejayoz, well now I actually set the protected $proxies = '*', and it works now. Thank you very much. If u care enough to post it as an answer (instead of a comment), i will select it as best answer. Else I'll select Alexander Emilianov's.

Comment: Glad that helped. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku's load balancing setup means the indication of whether the request is HTTP or HTTPS comes from the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header. (Laravel also needs [the `X-Forwarded-For` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto) to get the users' real IP addresses, incidentally.)

By default, Laravel doesn't trust these headers (as in a different setup it might come from a malicious client), so none of the requests will be detected as HTTPS. You can fix this by [configuring the Laravel trusted proxy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies) to trust the header.

In the default config, just setting `$proxies = '*',` will do the trick, and is safe on Heroku because the load balancers can't be bypassed by end users.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to change the URL of your app to `https://example.com` in the configuration file (.env file as an example). Just write APP_URL=https://example.com

**But**, when you use Heroku - their balancers can route your requests to `https://yourDomain.com` to your application over HTTP. So, the Laravel app receives the request to `http://yourDomain.com` and decides that you need a response with HTTP links.

As @seejayoz said you need to configure trusted [proxies list for your app](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies).

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use withPath (or setPath alias) :

```
$pagi=$answers->simplePaginate(3); 
$pagi->withPath("https://link/xxx/"); 
return $pagi;
```